# Linux kernel development

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, kernel, cron

I want to run some script/binary after system start and every 1000 ms (for example) inside Linux kernel (without the use of software as a crontab and kernel modules). Where can I put such code:

```c
#include <linux/kmod.h>

char *envp[] = { "HOME=/", NULL };
char *argv[] = { "/bin/ls", NULL };

call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use kernel timer API:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-timers-list/

> The simplest method is a call to setup_timer, which initializes the timer and sets the user-provided callback function and context. Otherwise, the user can set these values (function and data) in the timer and simply call init_timer. Note that init_timer is called internally by setup_timer"
>
> ```
> void init_timer( struct timer_list *timer );
> void setup_timer( struct timer_list *timer, 
>                  void (*function)(unsigned long), unsigned long data );
> ```